# Eclipse device not showing in device chooser

Tags: android, ddms

I am trying to run hello world program as specified here -

[Creating an Android Project](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html)

However my Sony ericson xperia does not show up in run configuration or on the android device choser

It shows up in the DDMS so i don't know why it doesn't work

My phone also shows up when i type adb devices in command prompt

I have downloaded sony pc companion and set USB Debugging on on my phone

Yet it still does not show up

Comment: are you using Windows or Mac? In Windows you have to download an additional driver for your device.

Comment: Did you install Android plugin for Eclipse properly? Go to Window -> Preferences -> Android: what u see?

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but sometimes I have to unplug the device, turn USB debugging off then back on, plug it back in and it works. If you have all of the correct software installed as others have said then it might be worth trying

Comment: Are you sure that you enable the debugging mode in your phone, because i think that it can provoke problems to recognize and access your to your phone from the computer if not

Comment: I know the issue was random in your case, plugging and unplugging the cable worked. But I am posting this for the benefit of others for whom the case might not be so. Another reason which may cause this is your device running a lower Android version than that specified in the app's manifest as `android:minSdkVersion`

Answer (score 1):

To codeMagic - yeah that did it thanks as soon as i unplugged my cable and put it back in it worked!!!